# Creating a live database (or leader board) for a website

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sqlite, web, database

I have created a small javascript game for my website. I want to include a leaderboard but don't know what type of database to use - MongoDB, SQLite, ect. I know SQLite is server-less, but does this mean it wouldn't work for my website? Furthermore, how would these databases be updated? If I'm hosting my website through github, wouldn't a git push be required every time an update was needed?

Comment: GitHub Only supports static frontend websites.
First, decide which language do you want to use based in backend and with which database.
Many courses are available for all the languages and databases you can learn from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github is static. That means you need to use something like [Firebase](http://firebase.google.com) to have updating content.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've been playing around with it for hours and can't seem to figure it out - even with the docs. I should be able to embed this right into my javascript game, right? As of now it doesnt update the firebase when I use a function like: `function writeUserData(userId, name, email) {
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email
  });
}` Is there a good tutorial that you'd suggest following? I'm just a little over my head. Thanks again.

Comment: @sam https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup.
also, can you accept ananswer to get this off the front page

Comment: I attempted to follow the setup to no avail. I was aiming to have this implemented into a javascript game I already have. If I'm running the game through flask to test will this still work? I have no idea how to determine if I'm connecting to the database ect.